# Function not recognized in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this error "Method strbtwn does not exist"
I've added strbtwn function to Str.php in Illuminate\Support

```
/**
 * Formats release date before returning.
 * 
 * @param  string $s
 * @param  string $start 
 * @param  string $end 
 * @return array
 */
public static function strbtwn($s,$start,$end)
{
    $i = strpos($s,$start);
    $j = strpos($s,$end,$i);
    return $i===false||$j===false? false: substr(substr($s,$i,$j-$i),strlen($start));
}
```

In my model I have this: `$listt = Illuminate\Support\Str::strbtwn($value,"<d>","</d>");`

What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a bad practice to directly edit the files over at `Illuminate\Support`, or any files in the `vendor` directory.

You can create a new class and extend it and add your method there.

For example,

`// create new file NewStr.php`

```
<?php

class NewStr extends Illuminate\Support\Str
{
    public static function strbtwn($s, $start, $end)
    {
        $i = strpos($s, $start);
        $j = strpos($s, $end, $i);
        return $i === false || $j === false ? false : substr(substr($s, $i, $j - $i), strlen($start));
    }

}
```

Now to call it:

```
$list = NewStr::strbtwn($value,"<d>","</d>");
```

That should do it.